# Excel 2010 Ignoring Year when performing Format(DateAdd("d", i, <some date>), "[$-409]d-mmm;@")

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, dateadd

I'm using Excel 2010 VBA and I'm creating a basic timeline.  Here is the snippet of code that creates some column headers, in the form of "D-MMM", based off of a start date and skipping weekends.

```
   i = 0
' Add column headers based on the day of the week. Skip working on Saturday and Sunday; do not show weekends
Do
    ' D-MMM format = "[$-409]d-mmm;@"
    ActiveCell.Value = Format(DateAdd("d", i, dteLowestStartDate), "[$-409]d-mmm;@")
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)

    ' IF it's a weekend do not print those days in the column
    If Format(ActiveCell.Value, "dddd") = "Friday" Then
        ' Skip Saturday, Sunday
        i = i + 3
      Else
        ' Weekday
        i = i + 1
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
'End processing more column headers once the start date + index(i) is a few days greater then end date
Loop Until DateAdd("d", i, dteLowestStartDate) > DateAdd("d", 3, dteHighestStartDate)
```

The code executes and displays the column headers correctly.  The issue I have is that when January 1 comes around, it keeps the current year (today that is 2011) but I expected it to be 2012.

As a test, I remove the `FORMAT(... ", "[$-409]d-mmm;@")` part, so it just reads `DateAdd("d", i, dteLowestStartDate)` rerun, and it correctly increments the year on Jan 1 but then subsequent code I use that makes use of the `Application.Match` function fails.

Any idea how to make the column headers (text in top row, spanning multiple columns) correctly increment the year with `DateAdd` and with the dd-mmm format?  OR should I be looking at changing my `Application.Match()` so it doesn't return error 2042?

Here is where the Match fails:

```
colStartDate = Application.Match(CLng(dteStartDate), Range(colLetter & "1:XFD1"), 0)
```

Comment: since I can't self-answer: Looks like if I just change my `FORMAT()` function to `Format(DateAdd("d", i, dteLowestStartDate), "Short Date")` it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I just change my `FORMAT()` function to `Format(DateAdd("d", i, dteLowestStartDate), "Short Date")` it works ok.